# How to extract common factors of trigonometric functions using sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I am new to using sympy. I checked the tutorial on the official website. There is only the "sym.collect" function for extracting common factors, but it does not support the common factors of trigonometric functions.
Here is my code:

```
F0,w = symbols('F0,w')
m1,m2,c,k1,k2,t = symbols('m1,m2,c,k1,k2,t')
c1, c2, d1, d2 = symbols('c1,c2,d1,d2')
res = -F0*sin(t*w) + c*c1*w*cos(t*w) - c*c2*w*sin(t*w) - c*d1*w*cos(t*w) + \
c*d2*w*sin(t*w) + c1*k1*sin(t*w) + c1*k2*sin(t*w) - \
c1*m1*w**2*sin(t*w) + c2*k1*cos(t*w) + c2*k2*cos(t*w) - c2 * \
m1*w**2*cos(t*w) - d1*k2*sin(t*w) - d2*k2*cos(t*w)
sym.collect(res,sin)
```

turn out:

```
ValueError: keyfunc gave non-binary output
```

The result I want to get is:

```
  sin(wt)*(-F0- c*c2*w +  c*d2*w + ....) + cos(wt)*(c*c1*w + ...)
```

So how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The collection can be done by passing one or more expressions, too:

```
collect(mid, (sin(t*w), cos(t*w)))
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot and simplified the code a lot.

Comment: Soon, you should be able to get coefficients of t-dependent terms with `cd = expr.as_coefficients_dict(t)` and then `expr = Add(*[k*v for k,v in cd.items()])`. I wonder if `collect` should have a non-exact option so you could collect on anything that has `t` instead of powers of `t`. It already uses `exact=False` to allow for powers.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it.

```
q = symbols('q')
mid = sym.collect(res1.subs(cos(t*w), q), q).subs(q, cos(t*w))
```

Comment: mid = sym.collect(mid.subs(sin(t*w), q), q).subs(q, sin(t*w))

Comment: You can [edit] your post if necessary, rather than posting additional information as comments